# Как синхронизировать phpstorm с github аккаунтом

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

Как синхронизировать phpstorm с github аккаунтом, чтобы phpstorm автоматически сам постил все обновления кода...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не бывать такому!

Как PHPStorm будет постить обновления кода, если он не знает, что обновилось, где, когда можно считать код завершенным? А вдруг он сохранит, пока вы пишете — да так и останется полстроки.

Тот процесс, в котором сохраняются обновления кода, называется «контроль версий». Осуществляется он с помощью систем контроля версий, одной из которых является Git. GitHub — это сайт, предоставляющий удаленные хранилища (репозитории) Git.

Одна из идей контроля версий в том, что вы сами должны выбрать момент, когда ваш код является в какой-то степени завершенным и сохранить его. Поэтому идея автоматического сохранения не имеет большого смысла.

Контроль версий — неотъемлемая часть работы разработчика ПО. Если хотите развиваться в профессии — придётся освоить.

Для Git входная точка тут: [Git Pro (на русском)](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ru/v1)

Задавая новые вопросы про Git, используйте метку [git](/questions/tagged/git). Кстати, по ней уже есть достаточно много хороших вопросов и ответов.

Answer (score 1):

В официальном мануале все подробно расписано

[Using GitHub Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-github-integration.html)

Comment: Хорошая ссылка, плюсанул )